# Carnot's engine

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

Why do we use isothermal process in Carnot's engine?
I think it should be isobaric process, because when we heat the gas it goes expanding to keep the pressure constant.
Why is my thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking why it is isothermal if the gas is expanding...

It's true that the gas does expand. This decreases pressure, and hence it would decrease temperature. However, you're missing the fact that **you attach a hot source** during this proccess.

The process is isothermal, precisely because we force it to be isothermal. In normal conditions, temperature would decrease; but since we heat it up again, the temperature is constant. In fact, we heat it IN ORDER TO keep the temeprature constant.

I think you're thinking it backwards; you're thinking about a vessel to which you add heat and then it expands... It's the other way around: it first expands (not because of adding heat, but because of the mechanism). It first expands, and then we add heat to prevent it from colding.

Comment: So, we are assuming that when we attach the source to the gas, the temperature of the gas changes to the temperature of the source in no time. Then, the gas tries to do some work by losing some of it's internal energy. But, the source is still attached to the gas. The source provides some heat compensating for the loss in internal energy resulting in an isothermal process. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much it. In fact, that's the reason why Carnot engine is unrealistic... because heat transfer cannot be 100%  instantaneous. It's an ideal engine and it has the greatest efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

While the isobaric expansion produces more work for the same volume change, the reversible isothermal expansion is more efficient at producing work. That is because in a reversible isothermal expansion all of the heat addition produces work, whereas only part of the heat addition in the isobaric expansion produces work.  The rest increases the internal energy (and temperature) of the gas.

The Carnot cycle does not necessarily produce the most work for a cycle, but it is the most efficient cycle for producing work. The efficiency of any heat engine cycle equals the gross heat added divided by the net work done. The isothermal expansion part of the cycle maximizes the gross heat added for the same net work done in a cycle.

Hope this helps.